# Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/add-application.mk:199:

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

It seems I cant find the answer.

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk
F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/add-application.mk:199: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

Here is the NDKLOG=1

```html
C:\>F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build NDK_LOG=1
Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: 'F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d'
Android NDK: GNU Make version 3.81 detected
Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: windows
Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: windows
Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to windows
Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/prebuilt
/windows/bin
Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/prebuilt/windows/bin/
echo.exe
Android NDK: Host 'echo -n' tool: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/prebuilt/windows/b
in/echo.exe -n
Android NDK: Host 'cmp' tool: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/prebuilt/windows/bin/c
mp.exe
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/prebuilt/windows/bin/a
wk.exe
Android NDK: Host 'awk' test returned: Pass
Android NDK: Found platform root directory: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platform
s
Android NDK: Found supported platforms: android-12 android-13 android-14 android
-15 android-16 android-17 android-18 android-19 android-21 android-3 android-4 a
ndroid-5 android-8 android-9
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-12 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-12/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-12/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-12/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-13 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-13/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-13/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-13/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-14 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-14/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-14/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-14/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-15 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-15/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-15/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-15/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-16 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-16/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-16/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-16/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-17 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-17/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-17/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-17/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-18 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-18/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-18/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-18/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-19 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-19/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-19/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-19/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-21 supports: arm arm64 mips mips64 x86 x86_64
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-21/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI arm64 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/andro
id-21/arch-arm64
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-21/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI mips64 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/andr
oid-21/arch-mips64
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-21/arch-x86
Android NDK:   ABI x86_64 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/andr
oid-21/arch-x86_64
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-3 supports: arm
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-3/arch-arm
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-4 supports: arm
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-4/arch-arm
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-5 supports: arm
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-5/arch-arm
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-8 supports: arm
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-8/arch-arm
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-9 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-9/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/androi
d-9/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: F:/Android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android
-9/arch-x86
Android NDK: Found stable platform levels: 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 3 4 5 8 9
Android NDK: Found max platform level: 21
Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following target architectures and ABIS:
Android NDK:    arm: armeabi armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a-hard
Android NDK:    arm64: arm64-v8a
Android NDK:    mips: mips
Android NDK:    mips64: mips64
Android NDK:    x86: x86
Android NDK:    x86_64: x86_64
Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following toolchains and target ABIs:
Android NDK:    aarch64-linux-android-4.9:  arm64-v8a
Android NDK:    aarch64-linux-android-clang3.4:  arm64-v8a
Android NDK:    aarch64-linux-android-clang3.5:  arm64-v8a
Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.6:  armeabi armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a-hard

Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.8:  armeabi armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a-hard

Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.9:  armeabi armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a-hard

Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.4:  armeabi armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a
-hard
Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.5:  armeabi armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a
-hard
Android NDK:    mips64el-linux-android-4.9:  mips64
Android NDK:    mips64el-linux-android-clang3.4:  mips64
Android NDK:    mips64el-linux-android-clang3.5:  mips64
Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.6:  mips
Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.8:  mips
Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.9:  mips
Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-clang3.4:  mips
Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-clang3.5:  mips
Android NDK:    x86-4.6:  x86
Android NDK:    x86-4.8:  x86
Android NDK:    x86-4.9:  x86
Android NDK:    x86-clang3.4:  x86
Android NDK:    x86-clang3.5:  x86
Android NDK:    x86_64-4.9:  x86_64
Android NDK:    x86_64-clang3.4:  x86_64
Android NDK:    x86_64-clang3.5:  x86_64
Android NDK: Looking for jni/Android.mk in C:
Android NDK: Looking for AndroidManifest.xml in C:
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
F:\Android\android-ndk-r10d\build/core/build-local.mk:148: *** Android NDK: Abor
ting    .  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run ndk-build from within the top level directory of your project, not from C:\ as you have done.  Otherwise, it fails to find the files in the jni portion of your project, as you have seen:

```
Android NDK: Looking for jni/Android.mk in C:
Android NDK: Looking for AndroidManifest.xml in C:
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
```

This suggests that you also have the option of setting the NDK_PROECT_PATH environment variable as an alternate means of telling the tool where to find your project.  However, unix-style environment variables have often been a source of trouble on Windows, which at least historically had a tiny default environment size.

Comment: I already copied the file on my C drive and still it cannot read the file

Comment: That will not work, as it needs to have the entire project available.  You should cd to the top level folder of your project first, then run ndk-build from there.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that on eclipse.. BTW I'm new to this and really appreciate your help.. :)

Comment: Not sure, I always do my NDK work from the command line or as part of an automated build, rather than under Eclipse (even when the Java components are built through that).  I'd imagine though that there is somewhere in the setup window for that command where you can specify the working directory or an environment variable.

Comment: I cant seems to find the right solution to this problem. I should probably discard the possibility to apply OpenCV to my program

Comment: The simplest effective answer is to run ndk-build from the command line.  While there are other ways to solve your problem of the moment, if you are going to seriously do Android work, command line tools should be in your arsenal of capabilities.

Comment: I ll be just using NDK for OpenCV application but I dont think I really need it right now.